# How to get color of div with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been working on getting the background color of a div and add padding to the div i want to do this **WITHOUT JQUERY** I have the html but no javascript yet. I have been trying the other code from google but it will not work. What i am trying do not work so I am looking for someone who can get me the code for this project.
THIS NEEDS TO BE

## WITHOUT JQUERY

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div style="background: green">
     HELLO WORLD
</div>
```

Thank You.

Comment: Without using jquery acheving this can be possible using sass and less or if you want yo get the background color using jquery than you can do it like        div.style.backgroundColor;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ELEMENT.style.backgroundColor` will give you the CSS-Attribute of the Element. (You can also use it to set the color)

To set the padding use `ELEMENT.style.padding = "10px"`

```js
alert(document.getElementById("myDiv").style.backgroundColor)

document.getElementById("myDiv").style.padding = "100px"
```

```html
<div id="myDiv" style="background: green">
     HELLO WORLD
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For this particular example:

```
<div style="background: green">
    HELLO WORLD
</div>
```

You can just pick it up from the `style` object:

```
document.querySelector('div').style.background;
```

If it's applied through a `style` tag or a `stylesheet` then you can use:

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('div')).background
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.backgroundColor
```